# Select substring from an RDD in pyspark

Tags: regex, python-3.x, lambda, pyspark

I am running pyspark via python3 and currently i have an RDD `cities`

```
[u'California - LA', u'Memphis, TN', u'', u'London, England', u'', u'', u'Ohio', u'Burlington, Ontario, Canada', u'', u'', u'North Carolina', u'Wisner, LA', u'', u'', u'Beverly Hills, CA', u'Toronto, Ontario, Canada', u'United States', u'', u'', u'', u'Mineola, AR', u'Washington', u'Dubai UAE', u'Morris Plains, NJ', u'Nevada, MO', u'', u'', u'Georgia', u'New York, NY [Spanish Harlem]', u'Newark, NJ', u'Chicago', u'Brandon', u'Queens, NY', u'Beaumont, TX', u'Houston, TX', u'', u'San Antonio, TX', u'', u'', u'', u'California - LA', u'Detroit, MI', u'London, England', u'', u'Chapel Hill, NC', u'Oxford, MS', u'Dallas, TX', u'', u'', u'Berlin, Germany', u'New York, NY', u'Sao Paulo, Brazil', u'South Jamaica, Queens', u'Los Angeles, CA', u'', u'Middlesbrough, England', u'', u'London, England', u'Egremont, Cumbria, England', u'Garnant, Wales', u'California - SF', u'', u'Melbourne, Australia', u'Nashville, Tennessee', u'', u'', u'Berkeley, CA', u'', u'', u'AUSTRALIA', u'', u'', u'Jamaica, West Indies', u'Pasadena, CA', u'Los Angeles, CA', u'Cleveland, OH', u'', u'', u'New York, NY', u'', u'Minnesota', u'Norway', u'FR', u'Delight, AR', u'Humboldt, TN', u'Tampa, FL', u'CA', u'', u'Birmingham, AL', u'Manchester, England', u'', u'', u'', u'B\xe9zu, comme Superdupont, ne connait qu&#039;un pays : la France !', u'Newark, NJ', u'', u'New York, NY', u'', u'Aarhus, Denmark', u'Sicily Island, LA']
```

and i want a new RDD just with the state name instead of `City - State`, 
the common delimiter would be a word just before `,[space] [word]',`
what would my lambda function look like

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: if its `'California - LA'` i just need `'LA'` and if it has `Toronto, Ontario, Canada` i just need `Ontario`, so its basically the 2nd element in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", "Toronto, Ontario, Canada", 0)[1]
'Ontario'

re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", "California - LA", 0)[1]
'LA'
```

This basically finds words composed only of alphabets and outputs the second element in the list.

Comment: is there a function called `findall` in pyspark ?

Comment: `findall` is a function from the regular expression module `re` of python.

Comment: oh okay, how do i pass my RDD to that function ?

Comment: The above will be the lambda in the map function. Eg: `rdd.map(lambda x: re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", x, 0)[1])`

Comment: So i did this `ne = city.map(lambda x:re.findall("[A-Za-z]+",x,0)[1])`  and when i tried to view the elements of `ne` i get only 2 elements `[u'LA', u'TN']
`

Comment: what do you get when you view `city` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97746/discussion-between-datguy-and-user1952500).

Comment: To summarize the chat: there is some data cleaning needed and until that is done, a quick and dirty way to achieve the requirement without the cleanup is to use the same statement in a filter clause: `rdd.filter(lambda x:len(re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", x, 0)) > 1).map(lambda x: re.findall("[A-Za-z]+", x, 0)[1])`